# How to build a string that contains "

Tags: c++

This might be a dumb question but how to make a string using wsprintf that contains a " ?
I need to write a batch script that contains a file path.

so i need to be able to do like

```
wsprintfW(wszBuffer, ""%sfile.bat"", wszTempPath)
```

how can i escape that?

Comment: `"\""` (filler)

Comment: Cheers. I was trying to do it like this wsprintfW(wszTempPath, L"\"%sFile.bat\"", wszTempPath); and was getting " for all chars. Created into new buffer and was ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape characters with a backslash:

```
"\"%sfile.bat\""
```

or, since C++11, use raw strings literals:

```
R"("%sfile.bat")"
```

Comment: can you change "since 2011" to "since C++11", because compilers don't check the date when parsing strings?

Comment: @risingDarkness: That's a rather wilful misunderstanding of what I wrote, but I've made the change in case anyone else shares your level of pedantry.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: We're programmers.  We're pedantic by nature.

Answer (score 0):

Use backslashes to escape the quotes within the quotes.

```
wsprintfW(wszBuffer, "\"%sfile.bat\"", wszTempPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the character like this: `"\"hello\""`